# Не работает register в silex для doctrine

Tags: framework, php, doctrine

я написал приложение, которое должно по GET запросу /base/1 вытаскивать из таблицы значение с id 1  (в таблице всего одно)
но в браузере мне выдает такую ошибку:

**"PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"**

ниже идёт перечисление всех ошибок, я не буду весь список сюда копировать, но там есть такие строки:

"PDO->__construct('mysql:host=localhost;', 'root', null, array())"

или

PDOConnection->__construct('mysql:host=localhost;', 'root', null, array())

или
Driver->connect(array('driver' => 'pdo_mysql', 'dbname' => null, 'host' => 'localhost', 'user' => 'root', 'password' => null, 'port' => null), 'root', null, array())

как видно везде стоят всякие root null и прочие значения по умолчанию и я не понимаю почему, когда у меня в файле регистрации написано это:

```
<?php //registerdoc.php
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array (
    'doctrine.dbal.connection_options' => array (
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => 'testbase',
        'user' => 'admin',
        'password' => '123',
    )
));
return $app;
```

?>

в файл где идёт запрос в БД:

```
<?php //app.php
$app = new Silex\Application();
$app["debug"] = true;

require("registerdoc.php");
$app->get('/base/{id}', function ($id) use ($app) {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE id=?";
$adrs = $app['db']->fetchAssoc($sql, array((int) $id));
return "<h1>{$adrs['ip']}</h1>"."<p>{$adrs['comment']}</p>";
});
return $app;
```

?>
вот тут! ошибка происходит на строке $adrs = $app['db']-> .....
т.к. если выводить что-то командой echo, до и после неё, то после не выводится, так что ошибка присходит в этот момент

ну и на всякий случай сам index.php

```
<?php
require('vendor/autoload.php');
require('src/app.php');
$app->run();
```

?>

всё написано по стандарным примерам из мануала, я не пойму почему он не распознает настройки в файле регистрации

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот блин, закон подлости... 2 часа сидел не могу понять ошибку, как только задал вопрос, так сразу нашлась.. >_<

кароче вместо doctrine.dbal.connection_options надо было написать db.options